# How to create list of objects from tuples, then select object by smallest attribute?

Tags: scala

As question in my title, how to create a list of objects from a list of tuples, then select minimum from that list of object by smallest attribute to return it's index.

I have a list of tuples, for which I have created two case classes:

```
case class Animal(typeA: String, name: String, months: Int)
case class Animals(animals: List[Animal])

List((Hero, Dog, 8), (Ninja, Cat, 17), (Kitty, Cat, 12), (Snoop, Lion, 3) ... )
```

How can I convert this list to desired output:

```
Animals(Animal(Hero, Dog, 8), Animal(Ninja, Cat, 17), Animal(Kitty, Cat, 12), Animal(Snoop, Lion, 3) ... )
```

I can do it easly by parsing a JSON file, and using a flatMap, with asOpt method, which will convert my tuple to animals:

```
animals = feature._1.properties.flatMap(_.asOpt[Animals])
```

But as I have described above is with using JSON parsing, my tuples are in a list, so I tried this without success:

```
val raw_Animals = List((Hero, Dog, 8), (Ninja, Cat, 17), (Kitty, Cat, 12), (Snoop, Lion, 3) ... )
var animals : Animals[List[Animal]] = raw_Animals.flatMap(_.asOpt[Animal])
val ages = animals.map(animal => animal._3.toInt).toList
val minAge = ages.min
val index = animals.indexWhere(_._3 == minAge)
println(animals(index))
```

I appreciate any method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I feel like your Animals wrapper for your List[Animal] is a bit unnecessary, since you have to call .animals to get the underlying collection, but this should accomplish what you want.  You can leverage the [Function3.tupled](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Function3@tupled:((T1,T2,T3))=%3ER) function to get your tuples mapped to `Animal` and Collections [minBy](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.TraversableOnce@minBy[B](f:A=%3EB):A) function to find the smallest by age:

```
scala>   val raw_Animals = List(("Hero", "Dog", 8), ("Ninja", "Cat", 17), ("Kitty", "Cat", 12), ("Snoop", "Lion", 3))
raw_Animals: List[(String, String, Int)] = List((Hero,Dog,8), (Ninja,Cat,17), (Kitty,Cat,12), (Snoop,Lion,3))

scala>   val animals = Animals(raw_Animals.map(Animal.tupled))
animals: Animals = Animals(List(Animal(Hero,Dog,8), Animal(Ninja,Cat,17), Animal(Kitty,Cat,12), Animal(Snoop,Lion,3)))

scala>   val ages = animals.animals.map(_.months)
ages: List[Int] = List(8, 17, 12, 3)

scala>   val minAgeAnimal = animals.animals.minBy(_.months)
minAgeAnimal: Animal = Animal(Snoop,Lion,3)

scala>   println(minAgeAnimal)
Animal(Snoop,Lion,3)
```

Comment: Thanks result is as I expected

Comment: Can I conditionate using the above method minimum? I want to retrive minimum from object list, but minimum excluding first and last element of my object list. The problem arrives, when I try to get neighbours of selected object, if minimum is at the start or end will return OutOfBounds.

Comment: You want the relative elements next to the minimum?  There are quite a few ways to do that, depending if you want a varying length List[Animal] (get the index of the minAgeAnimal and then animals.animals.slice(minIdx - 1, minIdx + 1)) or if you want a List[Option[Animal]] of length 3 (you would have to add in a bit more logic).   You might be best off entering another question if that isn't too helpful.

Comment: Method you write above works very well, my List[] is static size with 35 elements, if my index will be 0 using min then I have no left neighbour, if is last same as for right. I need somehow to drop first and last element, select minimum on reduced list, and then append first and last. But reduced map index will be 0 again where it was 1.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.tupled` like so:

```
case class Animal(typeA: String, name: String, months: Int)
case class Animals(animals: List[Animal])
val raw_Animals = List(("Hero", "Dog", 8), ("Ninja", "Cat", 17))

Animals.tupled(raw_Animals.map(Animal.tupled))
// -> Animals(List(Animal(Hero,Dog,8), Animal(Ninja,Cat,17)))
```

Comment: This is result error: value tupled is not a member of object

Comment: That could be because you've got the companion object of same name, in which case, you can use this instead: (Animal.apply _).tupled

Comment: Yes, works Karl give me a good soution, this sems to work too, but first tupled says me undefined.

Comment: Ah, Animals.tupled wouldn't work because Animals had only one parameter, in which case Animals by itself would suffice. :)